# How to check a un-running CentOS installation system time or first start time?

Tags: linux, centos

How to check a un-running CentOS installation system time or first start time?

I have a Server with two disks, sda and sdb, I found each has a CentOS on it.

now I running the sdb CentOS system, I want to know which time I installed the sda's CentOS.

how can I know it?

or how can I know the sda's CentOS first start up?

when I tried the

```
# tune2fs -l /dev/sda2 | grep "Filesystem created:"
```

there gets error:

> tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block

Comment: If you are using ext family as file system, you can use `# tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 | grep 'Filesystem created:'

Comment: @TrynaLearnSomethin See my edited post. bro.

Comment: there is xfs type of `home`, `root` lvm.

Comment: Xfs doesnt support creation time. Xfs is default on CentOS 7